# I want to separate characters and digits and write those values into a text file

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I am using a query to get all the values values from Db i have a 8 columns in Db with mixed characters and digits. I need to separate characters and digits when i am using below technique for loop is not repeating 7 times it iteraring values only one time and i am getting only one value I am attaching following picture to check what values are present in Database

[image]

In jsp page i am using the following logic to get and separate values from Db

```
String str = "SELECT PATIENTINSURANCE.VISITSAUTHORIZED,PATIENT.PATIENTID FROM PATIENTINSURANCE  INNER JOIN PATIENT ON PATIENTINSURANCE.PATIENTID=PATIENT.PATIENTID AND VISITSAUTHORIZED IS NOT NULL AND PATIENT.COMPANYID='"
                + companyId + "'"; 
        DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess();
        ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
        String a = "";
        String number = "";
        try {
            List encList = dbAccess.selectAsList(str, 2);
            if (encList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < encList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("the value of i  is "+i);
                    List temp = (ArrayList) encList.get(i);
                    String visits = temp.get(0) != null ? ((String) temp
                            .get(0)) : "";
                    String patientNo = temp.get(1) != null ? ((String) temp
                            .get(1)) : "";
                    String letter = "";
                    System.out.println("the visits is "+visits);

                    int x = visits.length();
                    System.out.println("the size is "+x);
                        for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
                        char c = visits.charAt(j);
                        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                            number = number + c;
                            %><strong><%=number%></strong><%
                            File file=new File("C:\\sample1.txt");
                            if(!file.exists()){
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }
                            FileWriter filewriter =new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                            BufferedWriter bufferedwirter =new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
                            bufferedwirter.write(number);
                        bufferedwirter.close();
                        System.out.println("Done succesfully");
                        }
                         else {
                            letter = letter + c; }
                        System.out.println("Visits are "+number);
                    } }
            } else {
                System.out.println("values of list is zero");
            }
        } catch (Exception e3) {
            System.out.println();
        }}%>
```

The output I am getting only first value that is:
    wt45
I need to get output as:
    wt45wt45wt4588tyde66wt45wt45wt45
and in text file i need to print 45 45 45 88 66 45 45 45 like this
    But i am getting output as 
    45

Comment: What's in DBAccess class ?

Comment: are you able to show the desired value in jsp

Comment: :@Sanjeev It contains 'resultset = stmt.executeQuery(query);' code related to the database connection logic and i need to show and also i need to write those values to text file

Comment: and after that the code that is creating list. right? i would like to see that code as well. and does it currently showing desired result on jsp?

Comment: I am not accesing list to any field its only declaration itself.

Comment: When i removing the piece of code that is second for loop the for loop is repeating 8 values when i am placing for loop its iterating only one time it is not incrementing .

Comment: `List encList = dbAccess.selectAsList(str, 2);` this line is getting list from dbAccess. so where is this list is getting created?

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem with this code is that you are opening the file using FileWriter in the for loop. Move following piece of code out of the for loop:

```
File file=new File("C:\\sample1.txt");
if(!file.exists()){
file.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter filewriter =new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bufferedwirter =new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
number = " ";
```

And close file after for loop.